# Error Query in old MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am create query to Count table.

```
$Month = $_POST['Month'];
$query = "SELECT ANY_VALUE(AD) AS ad,
              COUNT(*) AS `Click`,
              DATE_FORMAT(ANY_VALUE(TIME), '%Y-%m')  AS `Month` 
          FROM `clicks` 
          WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%Y-%m')='$Month' 
          GROUP BY ad ASC ";
```

It's work in MySql version is 5.7.10 (Localhost).
Then Upload on webserver, the server use MySql version `5.1.66-cll`, but i am find ERROR:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION
>   server_dbname.ANY_VALUE does not exist' in...."

If I remove `ANY_VALUE`, can work in MySQL 5.1.66, but didn't work in MySQL 5.7.10
How to make Query work in Both Version ( New version and old version )?

Thank's a lot for answer. ( I am sory, My English isn't good )

Comment: MySQL 5.1.x must not have had support for the ANY_VALUE function. You will most likely need to update MySQL.

Comment: it looks like `ANY_VALUE()` was added in 5.7.5 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-5.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ANY_VALUE` function was added in MySQL 5.7, to allow you to override the behavior of the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode for individual queries. The default for this mode was changed to enabled in 5.7, so this allows you to modify old queries that don't list all the columns.

If you remove `ANY_VALUE` and want it to work in 5.7, you have two choices:

1. Disable the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode, so it will act like earlier versions.
2. Change the query so that all the non-aggregated columns are listed in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```sql
    SELECT ad,
        COUNT(*) AS `Click`,
        DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%Y-%m')  AS `Month` 
    FROM `clicks` 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%Y-%m')='$Month' 
    GROUP BY ad ASC, Month
```

Comment: Thank's very much for answer my question fast.. Great..!!! it's work in MySQL 5.7.10,, I will to try upload again on MySQL 5.1.66. I hope it's work also.. Thank's very much...

Answer (score 0):

The `ANY_VALUE` function was only added in MySQL 5.7 and therefore will not work if you are using a version that is any lower than MySQL 5.7. As @mkaatman in the comments stated, update your MySQL version to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query as it should work in both versions without disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY-

```
SELECT ad,
              COUNT(*) AS 'Click',
              DATE_FORMAT(max(TIME), '%Y-%m')  AS 'Month' 
          FROM `clicks` 
          WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%Y-%m')='$Month' 
          GROUP BY ad ASC
```

Comment: Thank's, I was used this query, only work in MySQL old version. in new version didn't work. Thank's

Comment: #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ads.clicks.ID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: check query now which I have updated...earlier as 'click' and as 'month' were using backquotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Oh, i see the different.., I will try it.. Thank's very much